# ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated c.emp_id

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, sql-merge

i have 2 simple table

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(40),
  last_name VARCHAR(40),
  birth_day DATE,
  sex VARCHAR(1),
  salary INT,
  super_id INT,
  branch_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE biodata (
  emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(40),
  last_name VARCHAR(40),
  birth_day DATE,
  sex VARCHAR(1)
);
```

i want to merge it

```
merge into biodata c
using employee e
on (c.emp_id = e.emp_id)
when matched then
  update set
  c.emp_id=e.emp_id,
  c.first_name=e.first_name,
  c.last_name=e.last_name,
  c.birth_day=e.birth_day,
  c.sex=e.sex
when not matched then
  insert VALUES(e.emp_id,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.birth_day,e.sex);
```

but Oracle says:

> **ORA-38104:** *Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated:*
>   ***c.emp_id***

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the `c.emp_id=e.emp_id` from `UPDATE` clause as it is irrelevant

(`UPDATE` will be done on the record of table `biodata` for which condition `c.emp_id = e.emp_id` is satisfied. so the record which is going to be updated already have the same `emp_id` as `e.emp_id`).

```
merge into biodata c
using employee e
on (c.emp_id = e.emp_id)
when matched then
  update set
  --c.emp_id=e.emp_id,
  c.first_name=e.first_name,
  c.last_name=e.last_name,
  c.birth_day=e.birth_day,
  c.sex=e.sex
when not matched then
  insert VALUES(e.emp_id,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.birth_day,e.sex);
```

Cheers!!